# Does $\text{det }F=0$ imply that one of its eigenvalues is 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let's say we have a linear transformation $f:\mathbb{C}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^3$, so let $F$ be the matrix that represents $f$ in the canonical basis, and we are given that $f$ is not injective.

The *question* comes here: Since obviously no injectivity imply $\text{det }F=0$, from here... **Can we infer that one of its eigenvalues will be 0?** Since I've seen in a lot of questions that from $\text{det }F=0$ they directly say that one of its eigenvalues must be 0.

Comment: The determinant is the product of its eigenvalues (considering multiplicity) , so yes.

Comment: @Peter wait so $\text{det }F=\lambda_1\times \lambda_2\times \lambda_3$?

Comment: Yes , where duplicates are possible.

Comment: Another way to see it is that determinants relate to volumes of parallelepipeds, so the parallelepiped formed does not have any volume. Therefore, the linear map cannot have full range, so it has nontrivial nullspace.

Comment: $det F=0$ iff $f$ is not injective, or equivalently $\ker f\neq\{0\}$, which is the definition of having $0$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: If there is some non zero $v$ such that $Av = 0 $ then what do you think?